# How to remove the HomeKit API from within your binary

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, entitlements, homekit

I received this rejection message from apple in the resolution center:

Guideline 2.5.1 - Performance - Software Requirements

Your app uses public APIs in an unapproved manner, which does not comply with guideline 2.5.1 of the App Store Review Guidelines.

Specifically, it would be appropriate to remove the HomeKit API from within your binary and resubmit your application for review.

Since there is no accurate way of predicting how an API may be modified and what effects those modifications may have, Apple does not permit unapproved uses of public APIs in App Store apps.

the app code I'm using is open sourced 
https://github.com/SuperMarcus/NineAnimator

I need help on how to remove the HomeKit API from within the binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove it from the `Signing and Capabilities`:

[image: Signing and Capabilities[1]

Then try to run your code again.

If you where using a `HomeKit` API anywhere in code, Xcode will show you where it is.